# How to change layout in my all action of zend framework2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In my project where i have two modules, one is the frontend and the other is the backend,Because there are two different layout on the screen so each,Now I can change lauout on a single Action,I want to emulate zf1, the controller there is a init () method, you can perform, so that all action to change lauout or have any way to work.

zf1 init() Method

```
class AjaxController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    function init(){
        $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    }
}
```

zf2 __construct() Method

```
public function  __construct()
{  
    $this->layout('layout/administrator');//it's not work
}

pulic funciton indexAction()
{
    $this->layout('layout/administrator');//it's work
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this post: [Module-specific layouts in Zend Framework 2](http://blog.evan.pro/module-specific-layouts-in-zend-framework-2)

Comment: Thank you that it was successful !

Answer (score 0):

ZF1 and ZF2 are very different in terms of their architecture. ZF2 is event driven; meaning that you will need to attach an event listener to the controller dispatch event or order for it to correctly set the layout.

```
class Module
{
  public function getControllerConfig()
  {
    return array(
      'factories' => array(
        'Namespace\Controller\Ajax' => function($cpm) {
          $controller = new Namespace\Controller\Ajax();
          $eventManager = $controller->getEventManager();
          $eventManager->attach('dispatch', function($event) {
            // Set layout or perform actions prior to dispatch
            $controller = $event->getTarget(); // Controller
            $controller->layout('foo/bar');
          });
          return $controller;
        },  
      ),
    );
   }
```